# R; lubridate addition of months gives NA

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I am calculating with dates in a For loop. I combine data from two dataframes. Tibble 1 contains variable A, tibble 2 contains variable B and C.
A is a numerical variable, B and C are both dates.

I want to assign variable A a new variable if date B is within the interval of date C + 16 months.

I used the following:

`if (B < C + months(16)) {  Df1$A = A+1 }`

For some dates this does not work. For example October 30th + 16 months = february 30th. The conditional expression fails as there is no true or falls and the for loop stops.

Is there a way to change C + months(16) to the last day of the month if the specific date (february 30th in the example above) does not exist?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%m+%` to add 16 Months.

```
library(lubridate)
ymd('2000-10-30') %m+% months(16)
#[1] "2002-02-28"
```